# RoR iterate through a group/each_slice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking to get the last 5 items in an array, but to display each item individually, not as a group.

Here's what I've tried below with no success.

```
@array = Town.all

<% @array.each_slice(5) do |a| %>
   <%= a.first %>
  <%= a.second %>
  <%= a.third %>
  <%= a.fourth %>
  <%= a.fifth %>
<% end %>
```

I can't figure out how to pull out a specific number of items and then to call each individual item.

Answer (score 2):

The method you are looking for is `in_groups_of` (https://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of):

```
  <% @towns.in_groups_of(5) do |five_towns| %>
    <% five_towns.each do |town| %>
      # [...]
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

---

**Update:** Maybe you want only the last 5 elements of the array. If so, you can simply call:

```
Town.all.last(5) 
# => array of (max) 5 Town records
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the last 5 items of an *Array* you could use `last` and then iterate them with `each`:

```
<%= @array.last(5).each do |a| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

But it seems that you want to get the last 5 records of a model; in that case, you could try this instead:

```
@array = Town.limit(5).order('id desc')

<%= @array.each do |a| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

> ... is there a way that I can have let's say the last 5 records of a
>   model all within one loop? maybe
>
> ```
> <%= @array.each do | a, b, c, d, e| %>
>   <%= a.description %>
>   <%= b.description %>
> <% end %>
> ```

You could use the *index* of each item instead of using `each`; for example:

```
@last_five = @array.last(5)

<%= last_five[0] %>
<%= last_five[1] %>
<%= last_five[2] %>
<%= last_five[3] %>
<%= last_five[4] %>
```

Although that wouldn't be DRY, so it will be better to stick with `each`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Issue I'm running into is I'm trying to get each ```@array``` without restarting the loop.  So where as this will go through item individual, is there a way that I can have let's say the last 5 records of a model all within one loop? maybe ```<%= @array.each do | a, b, c, d, e| %> <%= a.description %> <%= b.description %> <% end %>```  -  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @dgreen22 are you suggesting that you want to loop through every group of 5 and do something to that grouping?

Comment: @dgreen22 You can access each element directly with the element _index_; check updated answer.

Comment: @MichaelGorman Yes. Do something to each individual item in that grouping.

Comment: @Gerry - thanks for that.  do I have to use ```each_with_index``` or ```|a, index|``` for this to work?

Comment: @dgreen22 No, you are just using `[]` to access the valure of the item in the provided index. You don't need `each` at all once you get the group (i.e. last five items).